# If a user is not an Admin, he can't access application

Tags: google-app-maker

I am having issues that when a user is not an Admin, that can't access a published application.

The spinner just keeps spinning indefinitely when try go to published app url.

Under Application access in the Edit deployment screen I do have 'Do not restrict access to this application' selected.

Comment: Do you see any errors in browser console log?

Comment: Share a screenshot of your configurations.